# Upgrade PostGIS when not used as extension

Tags: postgis, ckan

I am trying to update a server containing CKAN software from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20. Due to this upgrade, Postgres is updated from version 10 with PostGIS 2.4 to version 12 with PostGIS 3.

I read online many guides that suggest to use `pg_upgradecluster` and then `alter extension postgis update;` but in my case I receive the error:

`ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist`

So I looked at a previous dump of the database that I am trying to migrate and postgis extension is not declared, instead there are many functions that recall PostGIS libraries directly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.box2d_in(cstring) RETURNS public.box2d
    LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
    AS '$libdir/postgis-2.2', 'BOX2D_in';
```

If I upgrade Ubuntu 18 to 20 and try to perform a dump of CKAN database I receive an error that says that `'$libdir/postgis-2.2'` is missing.

Is there a way to perform this upgrade?